# Determine if segue is unwind segue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard, segue

I have around 6 segues that perform the same action in the prepareForSegue method, however, I want to skip this action for my unwind segue but I can't figure out how to determine if the segue being passed is an unwind segue or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you setup the segues yourself, why not use an `if` test in `prepareForSegue` to skip the extra method call?

Comment: The only way I know of to do that is if I write an "if" statement that checks for all 6 segue identifiers I want to execute my code on. I would rather just use an "if not unwind segue then blah". As far as I know, you can't set an identifier to an unwind segue and there's no other way to determine this?

Comment: How about setting the `identifier` of the unwind segue in IB and then checking `if (NO == [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Unwind"])` in `prepareForSegue:`so the code only runs for the non-unwind segues.

Comment: How do you set up an identifier for an unwind segue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ah, nevermind, Robotic Cat had the answer, which is basically give the unwind segue an identifier. I couldn't figure out how to do this until I realized you can select segues from the pullout panel on the left of storyboard and set the identifier from there.

Thanks!

Comment: Beat me to it.  Glad you found the field in the Attributes Inspector.

Comment: Yes I forgot how i did it before until i saw this answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

`prepareForSegue` is only called in the forward direction. It is not called when you unwind. To handle unwind segues, you need to connect your exit button to an IBAction method that takes a segue as a parameter. This method will be called when you unwind.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them) has more details about how to use them.

Comment: I just tested this and Becca is right. Unwind segues skip prepareForSegue so in my above description, it's sort of a non-issue. Thx

Comment: This is only true for `segue.destinationViewController`. From the docs: _"In both unwind and standard segues, the source scene can implement prepareForSegue to send information to the destination."_

Comment: Confirmed you can check for unwindSegue.identifier for unwind segues just fine in prepareForSegue.

Comment: Your comments seem to contradict each other, @Travis. And my experience and [The Unwind Process](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591-CH1-UNWINDPROC) in Apple's tech notes suggest that `prepareForSegue:sender:` is, in fact, called for unwind segues, so this answer appears to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty new to SWIFT myself. But I believe theres some misunderstanding here. If you add an unwind segue yourself, prepareForSegue is triggered. But on clicking 'back' button that automatically shows in the navigation bar, the prepareForSegue is in fact not fired.